# family of ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Can somebody explain what exactly is defined to be family of ideals. Is it just an arbitrary collection of ideals of a ring or is there some structure is this family?

Thank you

Comment: Just a collection. It might be nested, say, but that should be specified.

Comment: @user31415 If there is any extra context you can add, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's just a collection.

Comment: @user127001 How is this not an answer to the question?  OP provided two options, and I responded with one of them. This is a suitable level of detail for a clarification of terminology.

Comment: (and I know how to use comments, by the way.)